# Saving an Excel .xlam addin file Failure

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

Using Windows 10, Office 365 Excel

This seems very simple but I can't get it to work.

I have a file `djAddin.xlsm` which I save as a `.xlam`. There is no problem if I save this to the default location `C:\users\djela\AppData\Roamimg\Microsoft\Addins` and then create the addin with

```
Addins("djAddin").Installed = true
```

The addin is created correctly and operates correctly.

However if I save it to `E:\ExcelAddins` and try to install the addin I get a

> "Subscript out of range message".

I have tried:

```
Addins("djAddin").Installed = true

Addins("djAddin.xlam").Installed = true

Addins("E:\ExcelAddins\djAddin.xlam").Installed = true
```

All with the same result

Can anyone please tell me what simple thing I am overlooking.

Comment: For what it might be worth, let me guess. When you enable add-ins Excel looks for them in a default location. If your add-in is stored elsewhere Excel can't find it, can't load it, and issues the error you describe. The cure should be to browse for the add-in when enabling/loading it. In this process Excel will get to know the path.

Comment: You have to use `AddIns.Add` if it's not already in the default add-ins folder.